# Replace characters B for V and vice versa, Z for S and vice versa in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

I need to replace characters. B for V and vice versa, Z for S and vice versa
in Oracle

```
DECLARE
lc_word_so    VARCHAR2 (500);
lc_word_lst   VARCHAR2 (500);
lc_word       VARCHAR2 (500) := 'VBZ';
ln_length     NUMBER         := LENGTH (lc_word);
lc_search     VARCHAR2 (2);
lc_replace    VARCHAR2 (2);

TYPE typ_search IS VARRAY (6) OF VARCHAR2 (1);
arr_search    typ_search := typ_search ('B','V','S','Z');
BEGIN
IF ln_length > 0 THEN
    lc_word_so := NULL;

    FOR i IN 1 .. arr_search.COUNT LOOP
        IF MOD (i, 2) = 0 THEN
            lc_search := arr_search (i);
            lc_replace := arr_search (i - 1);
        ELSE
            lc_search := arr_search (i);
            lc_replace := arr_search (i + 1);
        END IF;

        FOR j IN 0 .. ln_length LOOP
            lc_word_lst := lc_word_so;
            lc_word_so := REGEXP_REPLACE (lc_word, lc_search, lc_replace, 1, j, 'i');

            IF lc_word_so = lc_word THEN
                EXIT;
            ELSE
                IF (lc_word_lst IS NULL OR lc_word_lst != lc_word_so) THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (lc_word_so);
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END IF;
END;
```

I expect the output: 
BBS
BBZ
BVS
BVZ
VBS
VBZ
VVS
VVZ

But the actual output is:
VVZ
BBZ
VBS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution using `translate`, but it looks unprofessional:

`SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'B', 'V') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'V', 'B') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'S', 'Z') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'Z', 'S') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'BV', 'VB') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'VB', 'BV') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'SZ', 'ZS') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'ZS', 'SZ') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'BS', 'VZ') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'VZ', 'BS') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'SB', 'ZV') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'ZV', 'SB') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'BV', 'VB') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'VBZ', 'BVS') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'VZS', 'BSZ') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'BZS', 'VSZ') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'BVZS', 'VBSZ') FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT TRANSLATE ('VBZ', 'VBZS', 'BVSZ') FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with built-in functionality. The `translate()` function substitutes the character in the first pattern -`'BVSZ'` - with the character at the same offset in the second pattern - `'VBZS'`. Characters not included in the first pattern are ignored:

```
with cte as (
    select 'BNV' as str from dual union all
    select 'ZXS' as str from dual union all
    select 'BBS' as str from dual
    )
select str
       ,translate(str, 'BVSZ', 'VBZS') as trns
from cte
```

Comment: Well maybe some kind soul will take the time to debug your code for you. I'm not interested in highly inefficient alternatives to Oracle built-ins. The one thing worse than re-inventing the wheel is re-inventing it square-shaped.